# Completely messed up booting. Can't even boot from DVD

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm so sad I did such things, but about two weeks ago a got a new Lenovo u510 laptop. Of course that's not the problem :D. I wanted to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.

Everything was quite smooth, but later I wanted to change boot manager with EasyBCD. It didn't do what I expected, so I returned to default in EasyBCD. Now when I want to boot to Windows it says:

```
Windows failed to start. ... 
Status:"0xc0000098 
Info: The boot configuration data file doesn't contain valid information for an operation system.
```

I found many answers what to do, how to fix it with Recovery DVD. BUT when I wanted to set boot to DVD, I opened BIOS boot options and under EFI there were two times "Ubuntu" and two times "Windows Boot Manager". But CD/DVD disappeared? That's the main problem I think.

I think it has something to do with partitioning.

Notice: I still have access to Ubuntu. So maybe I can fix this from Ubuntu? How can I return that CD/DVD option to BIOS EFI?

Comment: "I still have access to Ubuntu. So maybe I can fix this from Ubuntu?" Nope. You have a hardware, bios settngs, windows or easybcd problem. You could try to re-install grub from ubuntu live BUT as you stated... you need to be able to boot from a dvd. Question looks offtopic to me even though I would rather be able to tell you how to fix it ;)

Comment: Does your BIOS have a "reset" option that you could try? That would not mess with the boot manager but it might restore some hardware settings so your DVD drive appears again.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the USB flash drive image of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a USB drive from it, and see if you can boot from it. If so, it *should* show you your recovery DVD as a boot option. (If not, be sure the DVD is inserted and hit the Esc key.) If this doesn't work, then there's something seriously screwy about your firmware. (Perhaps a firmware update would help.) If you can't boot the rEFInd USB drive, you could try installing the Debian package version to your hard disk, but that will change your default boot loader, which might in turn cause more problems. (In theory it shouldn't, but you can never tell....)

Comment: Thanks for comments. I also tried booting from USB but withnout any success. I'm pretty sure there is a problem with partitioning. Because deviced in bios efi are completely messed up. I'm looking for something to change boot partition. My boot is installed by "boot repair" from ubuntu. It is installing it on sbd8 ? And at the end writes something about boot partition position(it's too far from the start of the disc).